# Angular - How to pass parameters to a child component?

Tags: angular

I don't get the expected results :-(

app.component.ts part

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'hidato';
  public minRowsCells: number = 1;
  public maxRowsCells: number = 10;
  public bigestNumber: number = 100;
```

and it continues

app.component.html part

```
minrows = {{minRowsCells}}
maxrows = {{maxRowsCells}}
bignumber = {{bigestNumber}}
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"
    (click)="onDisplayMatrix()">Prepare Matrix</button> 
    
<div *ngIf="displayMatrix">
    <app-matrix [one]="minRowsCells" [two]="maxRowsCells"
    [three]="bigestNumber"></app-matrix>
</div>
```

The output of this is "minrows = 1 maxrows = 10 bignumber = 100"

matrix.component.ts part

```
export class MatrixComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('one') MatminRowsCell: number = 0;
  @Input('two') MatmaxRowsCell:  number = 0;
  @Input('three') MatbiggestNumber:  number = 0;

  constructor() { 
  
    console.log ("before first for loop this is maxrowscell " + this.MatmaxRowsCell);
```

and it continues.

The print of the console.log is "before first for loop this is maxrowscell 0"

this.MatmaxRowsCell should be 10 but for some reason it is not passed from the parent to the child.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The constructor is called before data binding is performed. Postpone initialization to one of the life cycle hooks, probably `ngOnInit()`.

Answer (score 1):

someone already mentioned, but put your code in ngOnInit()

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log ("before first for loop this is maxrowscell " + this.MatmaxRowsCell);
}
```

also, just a suggestion, I find it confusing and hard to debug when the variable changes names so many times. If it was me, I'd keep the same variable name throughout:

```
@Input('minRowsCells') minRowsCells: number = 0;
```

html

```
<app-matrix [minRowsCells]="minRowsCells"></app-matrix>
```